# Tutorial needed for BBB full installation

Tags: ros, path, beaglebone, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When an expert can write a good tutorial for installing ROS on the microSD on a Beaglebone Black, that would be sweet! I am struggling with the path and bashrc and directories, etc. I've got over one Gig stored on the microSD but the programs won't run from there yet. ROS wants to install everything on the eMMC but of course, it won't fit!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172176/tutorial-needed-for-bbb-full-installation/) by [Rodolfo8](https://answers.ros.org/users/18431/rodolfo8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2014-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I did a ROS install on a BeagleBone Black, I put everything on the microSD card.

It isn't possible or recommended to relocate the ROS debs to a different path on the filesystem; they MUST be installed into /opt

If you already have an OS on the internal flash, and you'd like to install ROS onto the microSD card, you can mount the microSD card on /opt and then install the debs. Note that mounting a clean filesystem on top of /opt will hide anything that's already there, so you should probably uninstall any of the ROS debs that you've already installed, and reinstall them after you've mounted the microSD card on /opt

If your microSD card is /dev/foo , you can mount it on /opt by doing:

```
sudo mount /dev/foo /opt
```

And then proceed to install the ROS debs.

If that works well for you, you can make the mount permanent by adding it to your /etc/fstab.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2